# Bash Loop To Merge Sorted Files Using The Same Output File?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I'm currently working on a larger script, but I can't get this single function to work properly.

```
for f in app1/*; do 
         sort -u $f "temp.txt" > "temp.txt"
done
```

Directory app1 has a few text files in it. What I am trying to do is take each file one by one and merge it with temp.txt to build an updated sorted temp.txt file without duplicates.

**Example:**

temp.txt starts as an empty file.

```
app1/1.txt
a
b
c
d

app1/2.txt
d
e
f

End result at the end of the loop

temp.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

The problem I'm running into is that the temp.txt file only has the data from the last file passed through the loop.

Comment: You can't redirect to the same file you want to read. The shell will truncate the file prior to starting the program whose output you are redirecting to it.

Comment: should `d` appear only once?

Comment: @ReutSharabani yes, all duplicates should be removed so it only displays unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems.
You are using the outputfile as input (as stated by others) and you overwrite the outputfile in each loop. See the next incorrect fix

```
for f in app1/*; do 
         sort -u $f "temp.txt" > "temp1.txt"
done
```

This code will reset the outputfile for each f. Remember: When you redirect to a file in a loop, always append (`>> "temp1.txt"`).

The problem seems to be fixed with the ugly loop:

```
for f in app1/*; do 
   cp temp.txt fix1.txt
   sort -u $f "fix1.txt" > "temp.txt"
done
```

The way you should do it is writing to output outside the loop. Since you start with an empty temp.txt you have

```
for f in app1/*; do 
   sort -u $f 
done > "fix2.txt"
sort -u "fix2.txt" > "temp.txt"
```

Or is @Andrey right and can you use

```
for f in app1/*; do 
   sort -u $f 
done | sort -u > "temp.txt"
```

or

```
sort -u app1/* > "temp.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, can I hire you to write a short script?

Comment: @Nickyb No, for 2 reasons. -1- I am only on S.O. for helping people and getting feedback so I know how I can improve my scripting. I have a normal job. -2- You should learn the basics first. Without some experience any script from a stranger would raise more questions and problems than that it solves.

Answer (score 2):

If all the files combined are not large, you can sort them at once:

```
sort -u *.txt > all
```

If the files are large and sorting must be done at one file level, you can do

```
sort -u $f all -o all
```

Comment: The script I'm working on is to remove duplicate lines from an entire directory. I need to be able to compare the appended temp file to the files in the directory one after another to check and remove duplicate lines from each individual file, so I'm not able to sort the files all at once.

Comment: @nickyb Why does it have to be compared one after another? Is there something in the temp file to begin with? In the setup you describe in your question, I don't see why one couldn't sort all the files at once.

Comment: There's no reason not to use the `-o` flag in all cases.

Comment: @BenjaminW. This function is part of a larger script I'm working on to remove duplicate lines from every single file in a directory so that every line in the directory is unique. I need this function to be able to create an appended temp file for comparison to check for duplicates in the loop. I'm basically building and appending a blacklist one file at a time.

Comment: @nickyb this sounds like a different task. Moreover, it is still unclear. For example, if directory contains only two text files with identical contents, then what will be the expected result?

Comment: @andrey I was just answering Ben's question. Nothing has changed from the question that was asked. I'm trying to find a way to loop through a directory, merge 1.txt with temp.txt, and then 2.txt with the appended temp.txt to get the output in the example above.

Comment: @nickyb I don't think that creating the list as you describe (`sort -u`), whether by merging or all-at-once, is going to help with the final result you are seeking -- elimination of duplicate lines from the files themselves.

Comment: @JeffY At this point I just don't see a solution. I've been struggling to find a way to remove duplicate lines from every file in a directory so that every line in the entire directory is unique. I may need to just create a program in c++.

Comment: @nickyb Even if *you* don't see a solution to the "larger problem", still, ask away. Don't ask something intermediate that you think might work (and worse still, it won't). XY problems are tiring and waste everyone's time. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @nickyb So your desired end result is the same files you started with, but each file has only lines that are unique in the directory?

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's exactly what I'm trying to do, but have been failing horribly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to **append** - using [double angle-bracket](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command):

```
 sort -u $f "temp.txt" >> "temp.txt"
```

This may be another way to do it:

```
reut@reut-work-room:~/srt$ cat 1.txt 
a
b
c
d
reut@reut-work-room:~/srt$ cat 2.txt 
d
e
f
reut@reut-work-room:~/srt$ sort -u *.txt > out.txt
reut@reut-work-room:~/srt$ cat out.txt 
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: You can delete my output above, but that's what the result is with using that sort line so it's not removing duplicates. Thanks for letting me know about append.

Answer (score 0):

The shell process redirections *before* launching the command. So

```
sort foo bar > bar
```

will first **truncate** "bar" to zero bytes. Then the sort command has the "normal" foo file and a now *empty* bar file to work with.

ref: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections